# Can't find a appropriate property attribute for a instance variable

Tags: objective-c

I'm new to this objective-c property attribute thing. Here's the code:

**student.h**

```
#import <Foundation/NSObject.h>
@interface Student: NSObject

@property int age(assign, readwrite); //I don't know what attribute it should have
@property NSString *name(retain, readwrite); //this one either

-(Student*) initWithName: (NSString *) n andAge:(int) a;
-(void) speakName;
+(void) smoke:(NSString*) thing;

@end
```

**student.m**

```
#import "student.h"

@implementation Student

-(Student*) initWithName:(NSString*) n andAge:(int) a {
    self = [super init];
    if(self) {
        [self setName: n];
        [self setAge: a];
    }
    return self;
}

-(void) speakName {
    NSLog(@"MyName is %@", _name);
}


+(void) smoke:(NSString*) thing {
    NSLog(@"Smoking %@", thing);
}
@end
```

main.m

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "student.h"

int main(void) {
    Student *student = [[Student alloc] initWithName: @"Markson" andAge: 29];
    [student speakName];
    [Student smoke:@"weed"];
    [student release];
    return 0;
}
```

for the the line

```
@property int age(assign, readwrite); //I don't know what attribute it should have
@property NSString *name(retain, readwrite); //this one either
```

when I don't give nothing to them, the compiler give me 4 warnings:

```
In file included from student.m:1:
./student.h:5:1: warning: no 'assign', 'retain', or 'copy' attribute is
      specified - 'assign' is assumed [-Wobjc-property-no-attribute]
@property NSString *name;
^
./student.h:5:1: warning: default property attribute 'assign' not appropriate
      for non-GC object [-Wobjc-property-no-attribute]
2 warnings generated.
In file included from main.m:2:
./student.h:5:1: warning: no 'assign', 'retain', or 'copy' attribute is
      specified - 'assign' is assumed [-Wobjc-property-no-attribute]
@property NSString *name;
^
./student.h:5:1: warning: default property attribute 'assign' not appropriate
      for non-GC object [-Wobjc-property-no-attribute]
2 warnings generated.
```

Please anyone can tell what attributes should be used for age and name properties?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@property int age(assign, readwrite); //I don't know what attribute it should have
@property NSString *name(retain, readwrite); //this one either
```

Short Note:

If you are creating property for primitive types like `int`, `float`, `BOOL` etc then use `assign`

If you want to retain the value then use `strong` or `retain`.

In all other situations you can go with `weak`.

And always go with `atomic`, and the syntax is like this

```
@property (<assign/retain/weak>, <atomic/nonatomic>, <read/readwrite>) <dataType> <propertyName>;
```

Comment: Can I make the getter and setter private, but moving the two lines in the implementation files?

Comment: `@property` only creates property for you. its `@synthesize` which makes getter and setter for you. However in LLVM there is autosynthesize. if you want a private property then instead of putting properties in .h use it in .m only.

Comment: I take the two lines into .m. And got this errors student.m:6:1: error: unexpected '@' in program
@property(retain, nonatomic) NSString *name;
^
1 error generated.

Comment: in .m @property is not required. Simply after the implementation put `{<datatype> <variable> ;}`

Comment: you mean `@implementation Student {
 NSString *name;
}`? Does this generate private getter and setter?

Comment: Yeah. not setter and getter. You can simply use `name=@"new name"` to set. And to get use `NSLog(@"Name is : %@", name)`. I hope this will help you.

Answer (score 1):

Change those lines to this:

```
@property (assign, nonatomic) int age;
@property (retain, nonatomic) NSString *name;
```

`readwrite` is the default one, so you don't need to set it.

Check this documentation:

[Encapsulating data in Objective-C](http://waracle.net/iphone-nsdateformatter-date-formatting-table/)

Comment: could you explain why they are nonatomic?

Comment: You should use strong instead of retain.

Comment: Nonatomic means that they don't have to be protected for multithread access, so the set and get is faster.

Comment: Nonatomic is not thread safety. If you don't need to have thread safety object you should use nonatomic become of performance.

Comment: if the variable is an object like name, retain is used. And assign is used when it's not. Am I correct on this?

Comment: Assign is used for basic types like int, float... retain for objects.

Comment: Atomic will ensure that a value is always returned from the getter or it's set by the setter, regardless of setter activity on any other thread. With nonatomic this is not guarantees.

Comment: I added a link where all your doubts about properties are resolved.